# How to manage DbMigrations files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

Perhaps something you also came across. I am using DbMigrations (Entity Framework) in my asp.net mvc 5 project and I'm starting to accumulate a lot of them.

How would one go and manage all these files. They are taking so much space in my solution explorer in visual studio. I'd love to keep them.

How do you manage your DbMigration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically just delete my migrations files, especially the older ones. Keep the 3 or 4 most recent files as they're only meant to be temporary. Typically they're just used during the build phase in your project, sort of like 'backups' of your DB schema and data because you'll be changing and fine tuning your DB a lot throughout your build. There are probably better ways to manage them, but I like to keep my environment clean.